# Push messages to clients in tapestry

Tags: jquery, tapestry, atmosphere, cometd

is there any way to push messages to the client in tapestry ? I tried cometd than atmosphere (for like 2 weeks)  both of them didn't work for me. I had some exanpe jquery conflicts.
My tapestry version is 5.3.6.

**For CometD**, those are the dependencies i am using:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.cometd.java</groupId>
        <artifactId>cometd-java-server</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.9</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.lazan</groupId>
            <artifactId>tapestry-cometd</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.18</version> 
 </dependency>
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.cometd.java</groupId>
            <artifactId>cometd-websocket-jetty</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.got5</groupId>
             <artifactId>tapestry5-jquery</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.2</version>
 </dependency>
```

This is the repository i am using:

```
<repository>
        <id>tapestry-cometd</id>
        <url>https://raw.github.com/uklance/releases/master</url>
    </repository>
```

My java page:

```
Object onChat(String message) {
        this.message = message;
        return myZone.getBody();
    }

        Object onSuccess() {
            pushManager.broadcast("/chatTopic", message);
            return request.isXHR() ? formZone.getBody() : null;
        }
```

My tml page:

```
<t:zone t:id="formZone" id="formZone">
    <form t:id="ajaxForm" t:type="form" t:zone="formZone">
     Message: <input t:type="TextField" t:id="message" />  <input type="submit" value="Send"/>
    </form>
</t:zone>

<t:cometd.PushTarget topic="/chatTopic" event="chat" update="replace" />
<t:zone t:id="myZone" id="myZone" t:zone="myZone">
 <h2 t:zone="myZone"> ${message}</h2>
 </t:zone>
```

This is the erro i got:

2016-04-07 13:58:10.377:WARN::failed app: java.lang.RuntimeException: Service id 'AjaxUploadDecoder' has already been defined by org.got5.tapestry5.jquery.services.AjaxUploadDecoderImpl(FileItemFactory) (at AjaxUploadDecoderImpl.java:23) via org.got5.tapestry5.jquery.services.JQueryModule.bind(ServiceBinder) (at JQueryModule.java:175) and may not be redefined by org.cyberplix.internal.services.AjaxUploadDecoderImpl(FileItemFactory) (at AjaxUploadDecoderImpl.java:25) via org.cyberplix.services.AppModule.bind(ServiceBinder) (at AppModule.java:81). You should rename one of the service builder methods.
2016-04-07 13:58:10.377:WARN::Failed startup of context org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.Jetty6PluginWebAppContext@3abbbb74{/homewarranty,C:\HomeOneSource40\homewarranty\src\main\webapp}
java.lang.RuntimeException: Service id 'AjaxUploadDecoder' has already been defined by org.got5.tapestry5.jquery.services.AjaxUploadDecoderImpl(FileItemFactory) (at AjaxUploadDecoderImpl.java:23) via org.got5.tapestry5.jquery.services.JQueryModule.bind(ServiceBinder) (at JQueryModule.java:175) and may not be redefined by org.cyberplix.internal.services.AjaxUploadDecoderImpl(FileItemFactory) (at AjaxUploadDecoderImpl.java:25) via org.cyberplix.services.AppModule.bind(ServiceBinder) (at AppModule.java:81). You should rename one of the service builder methods.
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.RegistryImpl.(RegistryImpl.java:183)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.RegistryBuilder.build(RegistryBuilder.java:177)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.TapestryAppInitializer.createRegistry(TapestryAppInitializer.java:200)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.TapestryFilter.init(TapestryFilter.java:109)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doStart(FilterHolder.java:97)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:713)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:140)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1282)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:518)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:499)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.Jetty6PluginWebAppContext.doStart(Jetty6PluginWebAppContext.java:115)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.doStart(ContextHandlerCollection.java:156)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:224)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.Jetty6PluginServer.start(Jetty6PluginServer.java:132)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.startJetty(AbstractJettyMojo.java:454)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.execute(AbstractJettyMojo.java:396)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.AbstractJettyRunMojo.execute(AbstractJettyRunMojo.java:210)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.Jetty6RunMojo.execute(Jetty6RunMojo.java:184)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
2016-04-07 13:58:10.391:INFO::Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:8081
[INFO] Started Jetty Server

Comment: Your question is quite vague. For example are you using cometd/atmosphere directly? Or are you using [tapestry-atmosphere](https://github.com/uklance/tapestry-atmosphere) and [tapestry-cometd](https://github.com/uklance/tapestry-cometd). What is exanpe? What errors are you seeing etc?

Comment: Hi Lance,
I have updated my post !!

Answer (score 0):

This error message is stating that two services in your registry are trying to use the same serviceId of `AjaxUploadDecoder`

- `org.got5.tapestry5.jquery.services.AjaxUploadDecoderImpl`
- `org.cyberplix.internal.services.AjaxUploadDecoderImpl`

You will need to use unique names for all services